# time complexity of program when 2D array is initialised?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int a[100][100]={10};
    cout<<a[0][0];
    return 0;
}
```

what is the time complexity of above program?
is it O(1) or O(100^2)??

Comment: Initializing an array that way is done by the compiler at time of compilation, so it's O(1) during run-time.

Comment: The above code does not set all element to 10. Only a[0][0] will be 10

Comment: `O(100^2)` is the same as `O(1)`.

Comment: To clarify: there is nothing in your code that can change. There's no `N` in it. It will always run the same thing. So, `O(1)`.

Answer (score 4):

- Initializing an array is `O(N)`.
- `O(k) == O(1)` (for constant `k`, `k > 0`).

As your array have fixed size, the complexity of the program is `O(1)`.

if you change your program to something like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
int main()
{
    int size;
    std::cin >> size;
    std::vector<int> a(size);
    // ..
}
```

There, the initialization of `a` is `O(N)`.

Answer (score 1):

All values in your code are constant, so its execution time is constant: O(1).

(Of course the actual time depends on the machine you choose to run the program as well as on unpredictable external conditions, like the overall system load at the execution time.)

Answer (score 0):

Time complexity is constant because consider allocating space with `malloc(sizeof(int)*rows*cols)` where `rows` and `cols` have been defined before.

Also, the array indexing happens in constant time. Therefore, overall it is constant.